# what signed 16 bits little endian mean in pcm audio buffer?

Tags: audio

I'm trying to read data, I want this data in numbers (int double float something i can operate with in order to make some dsp) from a buffer obtained from a pcm configured as S16_LE, (signed 16 bits little endian) but i don't understand how information is organized inside the buffer. I think 16 bits means that signal values are between -32767 and 32768 but nothing more..

Comment: yes, it's -32768 to 32767. Little endian just refers to the byte order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) refers to how multi-byte words are organized, supposing that a byte is an 8-bit word. For big-endian, ordering puts  the most significant byte first and the least significant byte last. This is the converse for  little-endians.

An unsigned hexadecimal number `0x2317` needs  two 8-bytes

- big-endian order: `0x23` `0x17`,
- little-endian order :  `0x17` `0x23`.

Comment: The little-endian order is 0x17 0x23